# Show: $\mu(A\Delta B)=0\implies \mu(A)=\mu(B)$

Tags: measure-theory

> > Let $(\Omega,\mathfrak{A},\mu)$ be a measure space and $A,B\in\mathfrak{A}$. Show: $\mu(A\Delta B)=0\implies\mu(A)=\mu(B)$.

Hey, I've tried to prove that, unfortunately without success yet.
$$
\mu(A\Delta B)=\mu((A\setminus B)\uplus (B\setminus A))=\mu(A\setminus B) + \mu(B\setminus A)
$$
Now I do not know how to continue; at first I thought of something like $\mu(A\setminus B)=\mu(A)-\mu(B)$ but this is only okay, if $\mu(B)<\infty$ and in fact I do not know that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $\mu$ is a measure, so $\mu(A\setminus B)+\mu(B\setminus A)=0$ implies $\mu(A\setminus B)=\mu(B\setminus A)=0$.

From here, consider drawing a Venn diagram to see how to finish the argument.

Comment: Ah! $\mu$ cannot be negative, so the only way to get $\mu(A\setminus B)+\mu(B\setminus A)=0$ is, that both summands are $0$. And then it follows: $\mu(A)=\mu(A\setminus B)+\mu(A\cap B)=\mu(A\cap B)$ and in the same manner: $\mu(B)=\mu(A\cap B)$, so it is $\mu(A)=\mu(B)=\mu(A\cap B)$. That's it.

Comment: @math12 Exactly. :-)

Comment: Cool, a very short proof. Much more easy than I thought it is.

Answer (score 1):

$$\mu(A\cap B)\leqslant\mu(A),\mu(B)\leqslant\mu(A\cup B)=\mu(A\cap B)+\mu(A\triangle B)$$